# How do I bind arguments to a C function pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments, bind

I have done some research about how to use function pointers in C and I was trying to do some model of an object-oriented kind of thing. So to model such a thing I have been told I would have to add function pointers to the structs, so that they would be kind of 'an object'.

As I am pretty new on programming in C, this question may seem a little stupid (or very easy to answer), but on the Internet, I just found examples concerning C++ and that's not what I am searching.

Here is an example I would like to show, so that you can easily understand what my question is about:

try.h-file:

```
struct thing {
  void (*a)(int, int);
};
void add(int x, int y);
```

try.c-file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "try.h"

void add(int x, int y) {
  printf("x + y = %d\n", x+y);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct thing *p = (struct thing*) malloc(sizeof(struct thing));
  p->a = &add;
  (*p->a)(2, 3);
  free(p);
  p = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

As an example I would want to have always `x = 2`, so the function pointer in `struct thing` would be this kind of pointer: `void (*a)(int)` and not `void (*a)(int, int)` anymore.

How can I bind the argument `x = 2` when passing the function pointer to the struct (line `p->a = &add;`)? Is this even possible in C? In C++ I have seen something like `std::bind`, but I wasn't able to do this in C.

Comment: AFAIK there's no easy way to do that in standard C. Function pointers are just an address of a function to call, no fancy magic in there. If you want to bind arguments, you have to explicitly write a function that calls the target function with the argument you want to fix, and use a pointer to this new function.

Comment: This is what other languages do with _closures_. C doesn't have them (except I think GCC may provide them as an extension).

Comment: But actually we can do it in asm like below, code in address of wrapper_func in heap:  
push ecx;  ecx = addr_of_wrapper_func+1;  call real_func(args we got);  pop ecx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function pointer has to have the same signature (type and arguments) as the function it points to, so you can't really do it like that.

You could wrap the bind and the call in another couple of functions:

```
struct thing {
  void (*a)(int, int);
  int x;
};
...
void bind1st( struct thing *p, int arg )
{
  p->x = arg;
}

void call( struct thing *p, int arg )
{
  p->a( p->x, arg );
}
```

You'll want to experiment with this a bit, but that should get you started.

Comment: Ok. That should do it, thanks. It's a bit less pretty, but at least it does what I wanted. I was thinking of a Stack e.g. `void add(Stack *st, Object *obj) { obj->prev = st->last; st->last = obj; }`. So in the `Stack`, which is basically a struct, I would have to define the function `void (*add)(Stack, Object)`. I was trying to avoid the duplication of the Stack, but it seems, that's not possible.

Comment: Just one thing to add:

Shouldn't `p->a(p->x, arg);` be `(*p->a)(p->x, arg);` ?

Comment: In this case, it may make the code read better, but it isn't necessary; if `foo` is a function pointer, you can call the function with either `foo()` or `(*foo)()`.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems，and I used the following method to resolve, use gcc to compile it work, use clang to compile it do not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*add_t) (int);

add_t add2(int x) {
  int add1(int y) {
    return x + y; 
  }
  return add1;
}

int main() {

  //add2(2);
  printf("%d\n", add2(2)(3));
}
```

Comment: It does not compile because it is not C, it is a compiler extension. And note also it may not be safe to use local variables inside the inner function (normally, only static ones are accessibles

Answer (score 2):

A way that no one have talked about yet is to use some JIT logic (I won't provide a working example right now, because I've not yet tried it, but I will use it at some time for a RPC library). This is not strictly speaking a C language feature, and it's feasible only on CPU/MCU architecture where you can write to an executable memory segment (it's possible on x86_64, x86, some ARMs etc.).

The principle is really just to construct a function dynamically that will call the wrapped function in a similar way python defines dynamically nested functions.

Some library you can use for it : libgccjit, libjit, gnu-ligthning, llvm etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution .

```
typedef void(*call_type)();
call_type bind(void (*f)(int,int), int a, int b) {
    void call()  {
        f(a,b);
    }

    return &call;
}

void f(int a, int b){
    printf("%d, %d", a, b);
}

int main(){
    call_type c = bind(f, 5, 4);

    c();
}
```

Comment: Nested functions *ARE NOT* part of any standard. Please specify you are using compiler extensions, and which...

Comment: I have tested the code and worked well for me on this compiler specifications  : 

gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.